# Discord.js How to make a command to get every member in my voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command in `discord.js v12` to move every member connected to a voice channel in my guild into a different voice channel. This is my current code:

```
// Move All
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "moveall")) {
    if (message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) {
      const channels = message.guild.channels.filter((c) => c.type === "voice");
      message.channel.send(
        "**Moved all members in your channel** :white_check_mark:"
      );
      if (message.member.voice.channel) {
        for (const [memberID, member] of channels.members) {
          member.voice.setChannel(message.member.voice.channel);
        }
      } else {
        message.reply("You need to be in a voice channel first!");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), so you would get members from every single channel and every single one would be moved

```js
//we are getting every channel from the server, then filter it so our outcome is going to only include voice channels
  message.guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type == "voice").forEach((voicechannel) => {

//now we are getting members from each single channel
  voicechannel.members.forEach((x) => {
    try {
    
      //we set the voice channel for every member
      x.voice.setChannel(message.member.voice.channel);

      //Let's log to check if everything is moving nicely
      console.log(x.id + "Was moved!");

    } catch (err) {

      //let's catch, inform about error and log it
      message.channel.send("Something went wrong")
      return console.log(err);
    }

  });

});

//we return a message that operation went successful
return message.channel.send("Everyone was moved!")
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in the console it says:                                
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, when i was editing a code I accidentally deleted `.channels`, try `message.guild.channels.cache.filter` instead of `message.guild.cache.filter`

Comment: voice.channel.members ReferenceError: voice is not defined

Comment: Look at the code more carefully, it's `voicechannel` not `voice.channel`